# openlayers 4.2 400 Error Code (Bad request)

Tags: openlayers, wms

I'm trying to load a WMS in my application, but I get the following error:

> 400 (Bad Request)

Confusingly enough I still get an empty image.

The corresponding request is:

```
http://sg.geodatenzentrum.de/wms_dop40?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=rgb&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&SRS=EPSG:4326&STYLES=&BBOX=112.5,33.75,123.75,45
```

I've tried setting layer projection parameters to 3857, 4326, 900913 and 25832 but none worked. QGIS also doesn't seem to like the WMS either.
So I tried simple getMap requests in my browser and the following worked:

```
http://sg.geodatenzentrum.de/wms_dop40?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=rgb&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&SRS=EPSG:4326&STYLES=&BBOX=5.625,50.625,11.25,56.25
```

The only difference I could find was a different BBOX parameter.

Does Openlayers create a wrong BBOX parameter or what do I have to change in my code?

```
var view = new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([10, 51]),
    zoom: 6,
    maxZoom: 11,
    projection: 'EPSG:3857'
});

var luftbilder = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://sg.geodatenzentrum.de/wms_dop40?',
        params: {'LAYERS': 'rgb',
                'VERSION': '1.1.1',
                },
        projection: 'EPSG:4326'

    })  
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    view: view,
    layers: [luftbilder]
});
```

**weird, fiddle works fine** [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wbhoxwsb/) (in Chrome)

Answer (score 2):

If you are seeing a 400 error from the server then you can't also get an image (blank or otherwise). I see some sort of access control error when I try your links.

**BUT**

If you check the capabilities document for the WMS you will see the supported bounding box is

```
<LatLonBoundingBox minx="5.42587260523" miny="46.9672880527" maxx="15.7908768234" maxy="55.1764096793" />
```

So it seems that your bounding box (`BBOX=112.5,33.75,123.75,45`) does not intersect the available map data, so you get a blank image.

In any case this will all fail to display (correctly) as you are requesting the map in degrees (epsg:4326) but your map is in meters (epsg:3857). Try removing the projection line in your layer and let the WMS server send the map in the map projection.

Comment: well my map ist still empty now (and console is still spammed with error 400s). BUT when I open such a requested Tile in a new Browser tab, the tile is loaded correctly. How to fix this?

Comment: like ignoring error code 400 and still showing the tile?

Answer (score 1):

Quite possibly the service is misconfigured, so not necessarily a problem with QGIS or OpenLayers.   Certainly if you are getting a 400 error, you should not also be getting an image, the response should be an XML exception.

When I try loading in QGIS, QGIS can read the GetCapabilities response, but won't show the legend, I also can't get the GetLegendGraphic to work as a direct link, so something is wrong with the service.

E.g according to the Capabilities response the following should return a legend:

```
http://sg.geodatenzentrum.de/wms_dop40?styles=&layer=rgb&service=WMS&format=image/png&sld_version=1.1.0&request=GetLegendGraphic&version=1.1.1&&STYLE=&TRANSPARENT=true
```

But instead I get an HTTP 400:

```
<ServiceExceptionReport xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
  <ServiceException locator="securityGate.RequestHandler" code="NOACCESS_METHOD GetLegendGraphic">NOACCESS_METHOD GetLegendGraphic</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

QGIS does generate GetMap requests but I only ever get HTTP 400 XML messages like:

```
<ServiceExceptionReport xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
  <ServiceException locator="securityGate.RequestHandler" code="NOACCESS_METHOD GetMap">NOACCESS_METHOD GetMap</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

> weird, fiddle works fine

One possibility here is there is some proxying going on in the background; Fiddler is able to handle the redirects, but perhaps QGIS/OpenLayers is not.

**Update**

I tried too with ArcMap 10.3.1 and get the same error (reads GetCapabilities, GetMap has error).

Comment: Interesting! does this error mean that my IP is not whitelisted or blocked in a way? How would one implement a way to handle these redirects (probably to the correct wms endpoint, whose url I'm not aware of).

Comment: It seems unlikely that the issue is related to white/black listing, as there is a valid GetCapabilities response, and you get some response with Fiddler.  Additionally if the issue is one access, then I would expect some other HTTP response (401, 403, 407, 412...).

Comment: According to the GetCapabilities response, contact for the service is dlz@bkg.bund.de I would enquire there if there are any restrictions on the service, or a different access URL

Answer (score 1):

This question is pretty old, but a colleague encountered the same issue with this service. And the answer is pretty simple. Some Layer are restricted behind a paywall or are just allowed for the Public authority. Take a look on https://gdz.bkg.bund.de/ to get more information about which layer are free and which not.